# Cannot resolve TargetName error

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Please provide answers in visual basic.
Just want to know the syntax for the `Storyboard.SetTargetName`.

```vb
Me._StoryMoveLeft = New Storyboard
DAnim = New DoubleAnimation
Me._StoryMoveLeft.Children.Add(DAnim)
Storyboard.SetTargetName(DAnim, "SmoothRectTranslate")
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DAnim, New PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty))

Me._StoryMoveLeft.Stop()
danim = CType(Me._StoryMoveLeft.Children(0), DoubleAnimation)
DAnim.Duration = New Duration(ts)
DAnim.To = newDestinationRect.Left
Me._StoryMoveLeft.Begin() '<-- ERROR OCCOURS Cannot resolve TargetName SmoothRectTranslate.
```

```xml
<Rectangle x:Name="RectSmoot" Fill="Lime" Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="20" Y="20" x:Name="SmoothRectTranslate" />
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Everything above is WPF, check your terminology, you peobably meant to say XAML in all those cases, didn't you? Also, where is that XAML snippet located? If it's in a DataTemplate or the like you of course cannot animate it from outside its scope, etc.

Comment: Hi. Its not a template. Just a simple page with XAML and codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

To use `Storyboard.TargetName` in code you need to create a NameScope, see the [documentation of `SetTargetName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.settargetname.aspx) for an example of how to do that.

*(By the way, if you have only one animation i would not use a Storyboard at all, it only means trouble, just call [`BeginAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590761.aspx) on the transform)*

Comment: thanks H.B. Please, can you explain "it only means trouble," a little because perhaps it solves another problem of mine at this time if I understand you right.

Comment: NameScope.SetNameScope seems not to be supported for WP7

Comment: @Nasenbaer: The trouble is right here, you need to do additional set-up to do the animation using a StoryBoard which is not necessary if you directly animate the target.

Comment: @Nasenbaer: If you have questions for a subset of WPF, i.e. Silverlight and WP7 **tag the question accordingly**.

Comment: If you mean, I should animate the object by using a timer this is not solution because I wanted to use the Bouncing algorithm of Storyboard.

Comment: It is already tagged... no, it was lost. I am sorry, I am tagging it as Windows Phone 7 theme. Sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by Bouncing algorithm? Are you **sure** it cannot be done withoutout a Storyboard?